# How to mock a given method of Laravel Auth facade

Tags: laravel, testing, integration-testing, mockery, laravel-facade

I want to test that the Auth facade, when `createUserProivder()` method is called, returns my user provider.

The problem is that with the following code, with the commented out part, the AuthManager is still the original, not the mock.
With the uncommented part, I get an error: `Mockery\Exception\BadMethodCallException : Method Mockery_2_Illuminate_Auth_AuthManager::validate() does not exist on this mock object`

I don't know how to test it.

I want to test a custom guard behavior, that calls the UserProvider when Guard's `validated()` method is called, and for that reason I need to mock the Auth facade, because it is the one that returns the User Provider.

```
public function testUserIsAuthenticatedWhenUserProviderFindsCredentialsMatch()
    {
        $userId = Uuid::uuid();
        $user = new User($userId);
        $userProvider = new UserProvider($user);

//        $this->partialMock(AuthManager::class, function ($mock) use ($userProvider) {
//            $mock->shouldReceive('createUserProvider')
//                ->once()
//                ->andReturn($userProvider);
//        });

        Auth::shouldReceive('createUserProvider')
           ->once()
           ->andReturn($userProvider);

        $result = $this->app['auth']->validate(['dummy' => 123]);
```

Method to test:

```
/**
     * @param array $credentials
     * @return bool
     */
    public function validate(array $credentials = []): bool
    {
        $this->user = $this->provider->retrieveByCredentials($credentials);

        return (bool)$this->user;
    }
```

Service provider:

```
class LaravelServiceProvider extends AuthServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Auth::extend(
            'jwt',
            function ($app, $name, array $config) {
                $moduleConfig = $app['config'];

                return new JWTAuthGuard(
                    Auth::createUserProvider($config['provider']),
                    $this->app['request'],
                    new JWTHelper()
                );
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just because you created a mocked class, does not mean it is automatically replaced in the service container. The auth manager is bound as a singleton, so you can update the shared instance in the service container by using:

```
$mock = $this->partialMock(AuthManager::class, function ($mock) use ($userProvider) {
            $mock->shouldReceive('createUserProvider')
                ->once()
                ->andReturn($userProvider);
        });

$this->app->instance('auth', $mock);

$result = $this->app['auth']->validate(['dummy' => 123]);

...
```

Comment: The problem is that before the test, the app is instantiated, and so whatever you do after doesn't matter. I found a fix after a lot of debugging

Comment: @JorgeeFG the instance method replaces the binding in the app...

Comment: Yes I got you, but what I'm saying is that the app is booted before the test. So before you can run the mock. I had to mock it at the Test Set up level, not in the test itself

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of debugging I found a point where I was able to do this:

```
protected function getEnvironmentSetUp($app)
{
    $this->mockUserProvider($app);
}

protected function mockUserProvider($app)

{
    $userId = Uuid::uuid();
    $user = new User($userId);
    $userProvider = new UserProvider($user);

    $mock = Mockery::mock(AuthManager::class)->makePartial();
    $reflection = new ReflectionClass($mock);
    $reflection_property = $reflection->getProperty('app');
    $reflection_property->setAccessible(true);
    $reflection_property->setValue($mock, $app);

    $mock
        ->shouldReceive('createUserProvider')
        ->andReturn($userProvider);
    $app->instance('auth', $mock);
}
```

However another way is to just create a UserProvider for testing purposes inside the Tests directory:

```
class TestUserProvider extends AuthServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        Auth::provider(
            'TestProvider',
            function ($app, array $config) {
                return new UserProvider();
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Then in the Test file

```
/**
 * Define environment setup.
 *
 * @param Application $app
 * @return void
 * @noinspection PhpMissingParamTypeInspection
 */
protected function getEnvironmentSetUp($app)
{
    // Setup default database to use sqlite :memory:
    $app['config']->set('auth.defaults.guard', 'jwt');
    $app['config']->set(
        'auth.guards',
        [
            'jwt' => ['driver' => 'jwt', 'provider' => 'users'],
            'jwt2' => ['driver' => 'jwt', 'provider' => 'users']
        ]
    );
    $app['config']->set(
        'auth.providers',
        [
            'users' => ['driver' => 'TestProvider'],
        ]
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but someone might benefit or give feedback if this solution is valid.

I need the Auth facade for a custom rule:

```
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
    return Auth::user()->current_company === $value;
}
```

To check this had passed we know that `Auth::user()` method will return an instance of `User` model or `\Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable`. So thought why not just fake the Facade like so:

```
public function testPasses()
{
    $fake = new class {
        function user() {
            return new User(['current_company' => 1]);
        }
    };
    Auth::swap($fake);

    $this->assertTrue($this->getRule()->passes('company_id', 1));
}
```

It seemed to work well and it's simple. I know its not exactly mocking, it's actually using a fake but works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Having been stuck on the same issue for a while, I figured out a rather simpler solution: Have the AuthManager retrieve your UserProvider dynamically from the service container. This way we change the methods underlying `AuthManager::createUserProvider()` instead of the method itself.

#### Before

If you are using a custom user provider, somewhere in your code (usually the `AuthServiceProvider`) you are already registering the provider identified by `$config['provider']`:

```php
// App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider.php

/* ... */
public function boot() 
{
    // Original implementation based on the official
    // Laravel documentation 
    // https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authentication#adding-custom-user-providers
    Auth::provider('token-user', function () {
        return new TokenUserProvider();
    });
}
```

*(If you're using one of the default providers (`database` or `eloquent`), you can still use this facade method to re-register / override it – take a look at the additional example at the bottom.)*

`AuthManager::createUserProvider()` will use this registration to create an instance of the configured user provider, so `AuthManager::createUserProvider('token-user')` will call the above callback. Realizing that fact the rest is simple:

#### After

Have the callback return an instance resolved from the service container instead of a generic new instance:

```php
// App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider.php

/* ... */
public function boot() 
{
    Auth::provider('token-user', function () {
        return App::make(TokenUserProvider::class);
    });
}
```

This way we don't *need* to modify the return value of `Auth::createUserProvider` but can rather modify the value it itself retrieves with one simple call:

```php
// tests/SomeTestWithMockUserProvider.php

App::instance(TokenUserProvider::class, $mockOrAlternativeUserProvider);

// Alternatives (more info below):
$this->instance(TokenUserProvider::class, $mockOrAlternativeUserProvider);
$this->app->instance(TokenUserProvider::class, $mockOrAlternativeUserProvider);
$app->instance(TokenUserProvider::class, $mockOrAlternativeUserProvider);
app()->instance(TokenUserProvider::class, $mockOrAlternativeUserProvider);
```

---

#### Without a custom user provider

Assuming you're not using a custom user provider, but one of the built-in ones: This following example should do the job:

```php
// App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider.php

/* ... */
public function boot() 
{
    Auth::provider('database', function (App $app, $config) {
        $connection =  $app['db']->connection($config['connection'] ?? null);
        return App::make(
            DatabaseUserProvider::class, 
            [
                $connection,
                $app['hash'],
                $config['table'],
            ]
        );
    });

    // ...or, using the Eloquent provider...

    Auth::provider('eloquent', function (App $app, $config) {
        return App::make(
            EloquenUserProvider::class, 
            [
                $app['hash'],
                $config['model'],
            ]
        );
    });

}
```

Now you can replace the provider with a mocked clone or a custom instance in the service container *at runtime* using any of

- `$app->instance()` (when you have an instance of `Illuminate\Foundation\Application` handy),
- `$this->instance()` (if your current context includes the trait `Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\Concerns\InteractsWithContainer`, which for example the default `TestCase` does),
- `\Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::instance()` (using the facade) or
- `app()->instance()` (using the global helper function)